# How I can set session variable on click button event before auth laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Please help me out.
I want to create a session variable when user will click on button then after login that variable i can call on home controller.
When I am doing the below coding session is remembering either user is clicking on button or not every time after login it is displaying 1hi.

The function is:

```
$('#sub').on('click',function(){
        <?php \Session::put('testings', true);  
        ?>
    });
```

and the controller after login where I want to display is below:

```
public function home($reset = null){


        // indexed previous documents.
        $this->createResourcIndex();
        $this->title = 'Home';
        $folders = $folderList = [];
        $userLoggedIn = false;
        $sharedFiles = [];
        if(\Auth::check()){
            if(\Session::get('testings'))
            {
                echo \Session::get('testings');
                \Session::forget('testings');
                echo "hi";
            }
            else{
                echo "hello";
            }
            die;
}
}
```

Please help me out where I am wrong.

Comment: by this code, you create that session by default. If it dose not work maybe the session has set before, for testing our code please use another key or empty session. @user2110253

Answer (score 1):

`$('#sub').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefult();
    $.ajax({
       'url':'file.php',
       success:function(response){
         if(response=='ok'){
           alert('session saved.');
         }else{
           alert('session Not saved!');
         }
       }
    });
});`

file.php

`<?php
/Session::set('key','value');
return response('ok');`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `php` from `javascript`. So your onclick handler can't work. Instead, you must make a call to some `php` file, like:

```
$('#sub').on('click',function(){
    $.get('path/to/php-file.php');
});
```

and in that file, you can set session variable.

---

**Edit:**
Suppose, we create a file called `test.php` and place it in the document root of your site. Here is the content of the file:

```
<?php
// ... here goes some initial stuff about including Laravel,
// ... such as autoloader, session start and so...
\Session::put('testings', true);
echo 'ok'; //this is for testing purpose
?>
```

Than you can do in your `javascript` the following:

```
$('#sub').on('click',function(){
    $.get('/test.php', function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

As the result, you should see an alert message in your browser with text of "ok". And a session variable will be set.

Comment: Didn't work for me I create on file and their set the session variable please tell where I am wrong